# How to connect through voip between Skype and another voip provider

Tags: skype, voip

How to connect through VOIP between Skype and another VOIP provider. I have a friend on Skype, and I'm on Vbuzzer.

How can I call him from Vbuzzer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is currently possible.

Vbuzzer does currently have support for MSN, AOL and Yahoo Messenger so that you can keep in touch with friends who have ID's on those IM services.

But currently it doesn't support Skype, though if there is a round about way of doing this then i could be wrong.

Comment: I have not been able to find a work around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward method would be to have your friend subscribe to SKypeIN. However, if you do not want to spend money, you could have your friend setup [free incoming on Skype](http://truvoipbuzz.com/2009/06/make-receive-free-incoming-calls-skype-ring2skype/). Then you can make calls to your friend's Skype number (a US local number) through vBuzzer.